# Kernel and ideal of ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb Z[x] \rightarrow \mathbb F_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number. Consider the map $\phi: \mathbb Z[x]
>  \rightarrow \mathbb F_p[x]$ which sends $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i \in
>  \mathbb Z[x]$ to $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\bar{a}_ix^i \in \mathbb F_p[x]$. What
>   is ker $\phi$? We know that ker $\phi$ must be an ideal of $\mathbb
>      Z[x]$. Give a minimal set of generators of this ideal.

I believe that the ker $\phi$ is all polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$ that have coefficients that are multiples of $p$. Is that correct? How can I more succinctly express that set?

How should I go about finding the minimal set of generators for the ideal?

I am new to math.stackexchange so please let me know if my question is unclear!

Comment: You're correct, the kernel is $p\mathbb{Z}[X]$, i.e. it's generated by the constant polynomial $p$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks, edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel will be any polynomial $p(x)=\sum a_ix^i$ such that $\overline{a_i}=\overline{0}$ for each $i$. This tells you that each $a_i$ must have a factor of $p$ and hence the kernel is $p\mathbb{Z}[x]$.